NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes (PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy)
Recentemente enviei uma nova versão de um APP da minha empresa na Apple Store e adicionei o arquivo PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy no Xcode conforme documentação da Apple, porém, recebi o aviso que faltava a declaração de API para NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes. Depois de acompanhar o histórico de vários outros APPs que enviei nas últimas semanas, cheguei à conclusão que projetos que contém acentos no nome estão vindo com declaração de API faltando, enquanto aqueles sem acentos são normalmente aceitos.
Resumindo, faço o mesmo passo a passo, a diferença é que alguns projetos tem acentos e outros não, porém os que tem acentos vem o aviso de NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes. Alguém sabe porque isso acontece? Já iniciei um chamado no suporte da Apple, porém não obtive resposta até o momento.
Trabalhamos com framework Ionic 3 e Xcode Versão 15.2
Aviso de API Ausente
Xcode Passo 1
Xcode Passo 2
Xcode Passo 3
Xcode Passo 4
Xcode Passo 5
Xcode Passo 6
